# Index match formula with IF statement

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, matching

I am having an issue with a formula for google sheets:

```
=ifna(IF($A14="TRP Drills",INDEX('Drills DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D14,'Drills DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0))*$F14," "),if($A14="DMT Drills",INDEX('DMT Drills DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D14,'DMT Drills DD Skill by Skill'!$A3:$A,0))*$F14,""))
```

This is working for the first If rule “TRP Drills” but it isn’t working when I change A14 to the second If rule “DMT Drills”

Can anyone see any reasons why this may be not working ?

Comment: Can you share the sheet to try it out? Also, if the issue was solved please accept the answer so more people can benefit from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in `infa()` will not evaluate to `NA` since you are returning `" "` when it evaluates to false.

Try the following:

```
=iferror(ifna(IF($A14="TRP Drills",INDEX('Drills DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D14,'Drills DD Skill by Skill'!$A$3:$A,0))*$F14,na()),if($A14="DMT Drills",INDEX('DMT Drills DD Skill by Skill'!$B$3:$B,match($D14,'DMT Drills DD Skill by Skill'!$A3:$A,0))*$F14,"")),"")
```

Comment: Thanks ! This has worked to recognise both the IF statements, however some of the cells I need this formula in sit blank at times and now they read “#N/A” when I need them to stay blank ! 

I thought that is what the ifna statement would stop ?

Comment: That’s it ! Thanks really appreciate It

Comment: Marios, The formula worked perfectly for the sectioned I asked about. I have just copied it into a different section and re pointed the nessercery cells in it, however the cells just appear blank and are not finding the value required. The only difference is I have more IF statements in it now, Should my additional IF statements read the same as the first IF statement or the second IF statement in the fixed code above. I ask as they end differently and I don't seem to be able to add additional IF statements and get a value to return?

Comment: `ifNa()` accepts only two arguments, so using this structure, you can't add more than one if. Stackoverflow does not allow for follow-up questions. Please post a different question with this issue and the community (including me) should be able to answer and assist. Thanks. @ElliotStratton